# What does $D(f(\textbf{x}))$ mean

Tags: notation, dynamical-systems, nonlinear-system

If we have a nonlinear dynamical system with $$\dot{x_1}=a-x_1-\frac{4x_1x_2}{1+x_1^2}$$ $$\dot{x_2}=bx_1 \bigg( 1- \frac{x_2}{1+x_1^2} \bigg)$$ what do we need to do to find $D(f(\textbf{x}))$? Is it like the jacobian?

Can some write me a formula for a 2x2 one please.

Comment: Yes $D(f(\mathbf{x}))$ is the Jacobian matrix; an expression for this should be easily found in your textbook. What exactly is the function $f$ though?

Comment: So the first entry on the matrix is x_1 dot diffed wrt x_1 and then the next entry (top right) is x_1 dot diffed wrt x_2 and then the bottom left is x_2 dot diffed wrt x_1 and last one is x_2 dot diffed wrt x_2?